# Entity Model - How to insert / update data which involves navigational properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am using Entity Framework, WebForms, .Net Framework 3.5
I want to update a record in database using entity model which involves updating a foreign key too, which has become a navigational property in Entity.

How can I do that? I have seen a way which involves another query like

```
Product p = new Product{
   ID = 5,
   Name = "Bovril",
   Category = ctx.Categories.First( c => c.ID == 5)
};
ctx.AddToProducts(p);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

How can I do that without going to DB ?

Comment: what do you mean by **without going to DB**?

Comment: @Miroprocessor, Here in above syntax, "ctx.Categories.First( c => c.ID == 5)" will go to DB and bring a category, where as I would like to use categoryID 5, which I already have to save the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (this works with EF 4 so hopefully it will work with EF 1 as well):

```
Category c = new Category 
{
    ID = 5
};
ctx.AttachTo("Categories", c);

Product p = new Product
{
   ID = 5,
   Name = "Bovril"
};
ctx.AddToProducts(p);

p.Category = c;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is "Categories" in this line ctx.AttachTo("Categories", c); ?
I am getting exception here that "The EntitySet name 'Entities.Categories' could not be found." System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: That is the name of entity set for categories. You should find the name in the designer in properties of `Category` entity.